# как перенести в проект файлы из тэга Link

Tags: html, angular

Создал простой проект на Angular

В файле index.html имеются ссылки

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Мне надо чтобы проект можно было скомпилить на машине, где нет интернета.
Как мне включить в проект файлы по этим ссылка, которые Он пытается тут скачать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно просто подключить шрифт локально:

1. Первую строчку кода можно убрать
2. Необходимо скачать ваш шрифт Roboto и закинуть его в проект. Я обычно храню в отдельной папке "fonts"
3. Вместо ссылки укажите относительный путь к вашим шрифтам

```html
<link href=""../fonts/Inter-Bold.woff2" rel="stylesheet">
<link href=""../fonts/Inter-Medium.woff2" rel="stylesheet">
<link href=""../fonts/Inter-Regular.woff2 rel="stylesheet">
```

Нужно подключить так каждый используемый вами шрифт у вас их 3 (300;400;500). Ну или можно все которые скачали подключить.

[Также можно подключать через CSS](https://snipp.ru/html-css/font-face)